# Search in Eclipse Help for RCP returns no results

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I have an RCP application with help enabled on the menus.  I am able to successfully bring up the help that I created.  However when I type in a search term there are no results returned.

What is required to enable searching my help contents from the Eclipse help engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resolution was to update the version number of the plugin with the help content to rebuild the index.  I was relying on the .qualifier but that is not sufficient to trigger the index being rebuilt.  Once the version was updated all new content was returned on searches.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the issue persists with a small RCP example, like described in this [Vogel's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCPHelpSystem/article.html)

[image: help page]

The required plugins are:

- org.eclipse.help.ui
- org.eclipse.help.webapp
- org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty

Make sure your help content is well-formed (not like in [bug 324854](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=324854)), and that there is no external interaction (like a firewall/anti-virus) with the webapp which will query for you the result of an Help search.

Comment: Thanks.  This was helpful to prove that full text should work.