# Search index not updated on new html content

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse plugin with a toc and some html file as integrated help.
**The index for search operation is not rebuilt when I change some of the HTML files.**

I have even tried to prebuild the index as described here:
https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fua_help_setup_preindex.htm

This is my Ant target:

```
<target name="build.index" description="Builds search index for the plug-in: com.marchesini.mas.rcp.help." if="eclipse.running"> 
<help.buildHelpIndex manifest="plugin.xml" destination="."/> 
<help.buildHelpIndex manifest="plugin.xml" destination="nl/en_US"/> 
</target>
```

**The build seems to be succesfull, The locale is en_US, from config.ini. 
But when I search the index in the runtime it's not updated.**

The only way I found to trigger the index rebuild is change the version number of the plugin as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12033859/11643143.
Is it really the only way to do it??

How to have automatically rebuilt on plugin deploy?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to trigger the index rebuild is change the version number of the plugin as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12033859/11643143.

Having the index prebuilt is usefull for performance reason, but doesn't trigger the new  index to be used by search engines!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, same version number means no changes including help content.

**As a hack**, in the **configuration area** you can delete the index in the subdirectory **`org.eclipse.help.base/index/`**.

For dynamic content you can implement the extension point [`org.eclipse.help.ui.searchEngine`](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_help_ui_searchEngine.html).

Comment: What do you mean by "configuration area"?? I'm developing plugins, not a  complete product..

I'm using the searchEngine extension point, but does this help in index builting?? The index should be built in advance by some other component, for the engine to work.

Comment: The index is only built when it is needed. If the index directory is deleted, the index is automatically rebuilt the next time it is accessed. There is one global index. Plug-in can contain a pre-built index which is used to build the global index instead of reading all files that are referenced by the TOC. Most settings and caches are stored in the `.metadata` workspace folder. But not so the global index which is stored in the configuration folder instead (programmatically get configuration area location: `new org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.ConfigurationScope().getLocation()`).

Comment: Eclipse also offers an extension point for your own implementation of a help search engine, which can use no or its own index. But I don't think that's a good idea in your case because that would be too much effort, would it?

Comment: I believe that creating my own index is not needed, in my case. 
The standard help index is perfect. I just want a "mechanism" to upgrade (or rebuilt) the index of my help plugin when it runs in a platform, at user site.
It should be like a "database version" with an update script... :)

Comment: I mean.. the only solution seems to be to upgrade the plugin version, which is not always the case...

Comment: Another thing would be "prebuilding the index" as I said in the question, but it's not working, myabe the documentation is old...

Comment: It's _don't call us we'll call you_ in Eclipse. What prevents you to include a timestamp in the version, e.g. `Bundle-Version: 1.2.3.2019-11-28_15-34`? I can confirm that prebuilding a plug-in index works (make sure, to create the index with the correct locale and Lucene version).

Comment: I have other plugins with the same version, and they don't change version when I update the help. I will try once again the prebuilt index, do you have a link or tutorial that might help?

Comment: Each plug-in/bundle should have its own [semantic version](https://semver.org/). Do not mix this with the version of the product. [The built-in help explains how to add and create a prebuilt index very well](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_help_setup_preindex.htm). By the way, I currently work on a [modernized help UI for the Eclipse IDE and the Eclipse Infocenter](https://github.com/howlger/Eclipse-Help-Modernized).

Comment: So I should change the subject of this question (or create a new one?) with "How to prebuild the help index" because I can't make it...
I edited the question...

Comment: You linked to CDT which are a different index of the C/C++ tools, not the general help index (use the [link of my previous comment](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_help_setup_preindex.htm) instead). Having a pre-built help search index in your plug-in makes creating the global index faster, but you still have to increment the version (at least the qualifier with a timestamp) since an unchanged version means nothing have changed. The main reason why this is as it is is performance (imagine if many plug-ins would trigger update scripts on startup).

Comment: OK, the link was wrong but I used the correct link when I followed the istructions.
So I will use semantic versioning for my plugin, which I think, will prevent other problems in the future..
Thankyou very much @howlger!

Comment: Great. If you want to know how to generate pre-built indexes for newer as well as for older Eclipse versions, ask this in a separate question (there is a trick using fragments).